# How to print protected object in php

Tags: php, zend-framework, object, protected

I am doing the login using twitter oauth functionality. I am getting the following object from `$client = $token->getHttpClient($config)` method:

```
Zend_Oauth_Client Object
(
    [_config:protected] => Zend_Oauth_Config Object
        (
            [_signatureMethod:protected] => HMAC-SHA1
            [_requestScheme:protected] => header
            [_requestMethod:protected] => POST
            [_version:protected] => 1.0
            [_callbackUrl:protected] => http://roomstayssvn.com/register/twittercallback
            [_siteUrl:protected] => http://twitter.com/oauth
            [_requestTokenUrl:protected] => 
            [_accessTokenUrl:protected] => 
            [_authorizeUrl:protected] => 
            [_consumerKey:protected] => b04fuaxLR2d035FN8tTkQ
            [_consumerSecret:protected] => NGPPovdXDnSpivNoMNIgA609ZJIB8GVKGgs6yEF8A
            [_rsaPrivateKey:protected] => 
            [_rsaPublicKey:protected] => 
            [_token:protected] => Zend_Oauth_Token_Access Object
                (
                    [_params:protected] => Array
                        (
                            [oauth_token] => 299516752-tksjJZUR7Q2gwrDRDpLOLCrYhySTGWz1SBwTKcRU
                            [oauth_token_secret] => 7S9R2FLuB0GT4vvy0GerThUnpkbSTeSalURib48Sx20
                            [user_id] => 299516752
                            [screen_name] => jogkunal5
                        )
                 )
             .....
             ..... and so on
```

I want to print `user_id` and `screen_name`. How can I print it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following should work

```
$user_id = $client->getToken()->getParam('user_id');
$screen_name = $client->getToken()->getParam('screen_name');
```

`Zend_Oauth_Client::__call()` proxies any method of `Zend_Oauth_Config`.
`Zend_Oauth_Config::getToken()` returns `Zend_Oauth_Token`
`Zend_Oauth_Token::getParam()` gets the value for a parameter

Read the docs from [here](http://framework.zend.com/apidoc/1.10/_Oauth_Client.html#Zend_Oauth_Client%3a%3a__call%28%29).

Its better you use a Good IDE that supports Zend framework.